# How do you subclass a backdraft component and include watchables?

Tags: javascript, backdraftjs

```
class Beer extends Component {
    [...component code goes here]
}

class AnchorSteam extends Beer.withWatchables('foamy') {
    [...component code goes here]
}
```

Will this work? Can I add watchables on the subclassed component?

---

Secondary question:

If instead I did this...

```
class Beer extends Component.withWatchables('foamy') {
    [...component code goes here]
}

class AnchorSteam extends Beer {
    [...component code goes here]
}
```

... would AnchorSteam respond to the 'foamy' watchable, e.g. if I have a `bdReflect: foamy` in AnchorSteam, will it respond to changes in the watchable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this feature is available by writing

```
class AnchorSteam extends withWatchables(Beer, 'foamy') {
    [...component code goes here]
}
```

`withWatchables` is a function exported by the `watchUtils` module:

https://github.com/altoviso/backdraft/blob/master/src/watchUtils.js#L762

A common use case is adding a watchable to a component...

```
class Beer extends withWatchables(Component, 'temperature') {
    [...component code goes here]
}
```

Indeed, this is so common, there the library provides some "expression sugar" (that is, it's not really shorter, but seems to read better):

```
class Beer extends Component.withWatchables('temperature') {
    [...component code goes here]
}
```

Regarding the second question: yes, `AnchorSteam` has the watchable `foamy`. There is nothing special going on here. `Beer` has a standard javascript getter/setter for `foamy` as part of its interface; `AnchorSteam` is a subclass of `Beer` and therefore will also have the getter/setter for `foamy` (assuming `AnchorSteam` has not overridden that getter/setter in the superclass).

The second question also asked if `bdReflect` would work in `AnchorSteam`. Again, the answer is yes.